# Determinant of augmented matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ real matrices. How can I show that $\det 
\begin{bmatrix}
       A & B \\[0.3em]
       -B & A \\[0.3em]
     \end{bmatrix}
\geq 0
$?

Comment: it is plain false, let $n = 1$, $A = [0]$ and $B = [1]$

Comment: do you have more conditions imposed on the matrices $A$ and $B$?  do they commute?  are they invertible?  are they positive-semidefinite?

Comment: I'm so sorry I had a typo. It was -B not B

Comment: It's false, as @JefLaga said.

Comment: @DonLarynx Jef's example does not hold now; a typo was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* By continuity, you may assume without loss of generality that $A$ is invertible. Then, use [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) to show that the determinant is equal to $\det(A)^2\ \left|\det(I+iBA^{-1})\right|^2$.